# How to generate a private/public key pair to use for a Linux server on Windows Azure?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, private-key

Following [Windows Azure documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/ssh-into-linux/), I generated a pair of private/public keys on an Ubuntu machine using the exact comment as given:

> openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myPrivateKey.key -out myCert.pem

When I open the private key in `puttygen`, the following error is displayed:

> Couldn't load private key (unrecognised key type)

The private key generated by `openssl` looks correct:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG6w0xAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEsAoIBAQC6OEZ5ULe6F6u2
Cybhqqfqqh2ao9sd2tpqB+HGIoMMHrmnD3YegRgZJIddTQaWKdwaKrYul21YNt5y
...
P0RyfL9kDnX/XmIOM38FOoucGvO+Zozsbmgmvw6AUhE0sPhkZnlaodAU1OnfaWJz
KpBxkXulBaCJnC8w29dGKng=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Note that the comments to Azure documentation (the same link as above) report that the pair should be generated using OpenSSL for Windows instead of `openssl` on Linux. This doesn't help, since the same error appears for a private key generated by OpenSSL for Windows.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh-keys and puttygen doesn't have the same format.
You need convert to puttygen

1. Open PuttyGen
2. Click Load
3. Load your private key
4. Go to Conversions->Export OpenSSH and export your private key
5. Copy your private key to ~/.ssh/id_dsa (or id_rsa).
6. Create the RFC 4716 version of the public key using ssh-keygen

   ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa > ~/.ssh/id_dsa_com.pub
7. Convert the RFC 4716 version of the public key to the OpenSSH format:

   ssh-keygen -i -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa_com.pub > ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub

More info:

http://linux-sxs.org/networking/openssh.putty.html

http://www.wellsi.com/sme/ssh/ssh.html